# FM updating Installation type in EANL table returns SY-SUBRC = 0 even if it fails

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I need to remove the space in installation type field of EANL table using ISU_DB_EANL_UPDATE function module. I have written a piece of code. But ISU_DB_EANL_UPDATE is always returning sy-subrc as 0. If the table is not updated, then also ISU_DB_EANL_UPDATE returns sy-subrc as 0 instead of not equal to 0. I am not able to find out the reason behind this. Here is my piece of code. Please help me in this matter.

```
LOOP AT gt_eanl INTO gs_eanl.
    ls_eanl_new = gs_eanl.
    lv_temp = ls_eanl_new-anlart.
    if lv_temp ca ''.
    CONDENSE lv_temp.
    ls_eanl_new-anlart = lv_temp.
    endif.


    CALL FUNCTION 'ISU_DB_EANL_UPDATE'
      EXPORTING
        x_eanl     = ls_eanl_new
        x_eanl_old = gs_eanl
        x_upd_mode = 'U'.

    IF sy-subrc NE 0.
      write:'eanl not updated'.
      skip.

    ELSE.

      write:'eanl updated'.
      skip.

    ENDIF.
  ENDLOOP.
```

Here output is always coming as eanl updated. I have also tested with a value of anlart having no space. But then also, sy-subrc is 0. Please help me.

Comment: How many entries do you have in the `EANL` table?

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified any exceptions in your call to ISU_DB_EANL_UPDATE so SY-SUBRC is not set. Adding EXCEPTIONS OTHERS = 1 will map all exceptions to 1, meaning that if any exceptions are thrown SY-SUBRC will be 1 after the call. This will tell you that something has failed but the FM probably throws many different exceptions, it would be better to catch these all in different values so you know what happened.

Comment: in the exception tab of the FM ISU_DB_EANL_UPDATE, there is no exceptions specified. What i will do now?

Comment: Find a better way to create the installation. [MDG](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_erp2005/helpdata/JA/9d/a35085b8ac0f4e9da5d169a003e2d4/content.htm?frameset=/JA/9d/a35085b8ac0f4e9da5d169a003e2d4/frameset.htm&current_toc=/JA/38/1a6c35a018d041e10000009b38f839/plain.htm&node_id=85&show_children=true#jump85) comes to mind. Or try FM  ISU_S_INSTLN_CREATE.

Comment: Actually, I am updating the installation type(anlart) of eanl table for a given installation. I am not creating any new installation. That is why i am using the FM ISU_DB_EANL_UPDATE. please help me out in this matter.

Comment: @GertBeukema The function module `ISU_DB_EANL_UPDATE` is an update function module, which means it cannot have any exceptions specified and should be called in `IN UPDATE TASK`.

Answer (score 0):

check other parameters return by FM: ISU_DB_EANL_UPDATE.

Comment: I didn't get what you are saying. Can you please explain it more clearly @Bhavesh?

Comment: check other parameters returns by this, as if it is returning any exception you can catch that.

Comment: I have debugged the program. But after the execution of call function ISU_DB_EANL_UPDATE, sy-tabix becomes 1 .

Comment: that means these many records have been read by the FM, you can also debug function module for better understanding as to why it is returning sy-subrc as 0 all the time.

Comment: Could not getting it. Sy-subrc is always coming zero for that piece of code. Please help.

Comment: In the exception tab of the FM, there is no exception specified. what to do now?

Comment: A) make a  copy of this module and add an exception. B) Check those fields after the call to the module, they might be populated (MSGID
MSGTY
MSGNO
MSGV1
MSGV2
MSGV3
MSGV4 ) , all of them are also in the sy-table.